# Need assistance performing a pivot from multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I preface this by saying I am new to SQL and have been learning on the job thanks to Stack Overflow.

I am running a query from multiple tables (3 in total), and I am trying to get the results for each unique identifier on one row. 1 of the table items has multiple returns, and I am able to write it to where they show as a max command in their own column; however, it still returns multiple rows for the same identifier.

Here's what I have so far:

```
SELECT tbl.1.field as ID, tbl.2.field as Name, tbl.2.fieldb as Product,
COUNT(*) AS ConfirmedSales
MAX(CASE WHEN tbl.3.field = 'Product1' then 1 else 0 end) as CustomCol1
MAX(CASE WHEN tbl.3.field = 'Product2' then 1 else 0 end) as CustomCol2
FROM tbl.2
LEFT JOIN tbl.2 on tbl.2.x = tbl.1.x
INNER JOIN tbl.3 on tbl.2.x = tbl.3.x
WHERE ((tbl.1.date between '01/01/2014 00:00:00' and 06/30/2014 23:59:59'))
GROUP BY tbl.1.field, tbl.2.field, tbl.2.fieldb
```

Results return as follows:

```
Row   |ID    |Name         |CustomCol1 |CustomCol2
1     |8048  |Jon Smith    |1          |0
2     |8048  |Jon Smith    |0          |1
3     |4044  |Max Williams |0          |0
```

I would like for the results for CustomCol1 and CustomCol2 to share the same line if the ID is the same. Is this possible?

Comment: aside from syntax error missing comma between the COUNT(*) and MAX() fields, and your sample of "tbl.1" etc table name references are trying to hide your database names, it SHOULD work, but you are not showing the count(*) column result in your set.

Comment: What is the purpose of the two custom columns with their 1's and 0's?  I'm just curious in case there is a better method to give you what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Consider moving your cases into a subquery like so:

```
SELECT t.ID, t.name, MAX(s.custom1) AS custom1, MAX(custom2) AS custom2
FROM #tbl1 t
   INNER JOIN (SELECT personID 
                  ,CASE WHEN s.product = 'product1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END custom1
                  ,CASE WHEN s.product = 'product2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END custom2
               FROM #sales s) s ON t.ID = s.personID
GROUP BY t.ID, t.Name
```

This will prevent the duplication you're seeing. If you're ultimate goal is something else, though, give us some more info, and I'm sure someone will have a good answer.